# Apache Ignite: Unable to start with basic XML config containing expiration policy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

I'm attempting to start Ignite with some XML configs, and I'm following the documentation, but I can't get it to start.
Here are my configs:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="default"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="eagerTtl" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
        <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                    <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

When I try using these configs, I get these exceptions:

> $ bin/ignite.sh /path/to/etc/cache.xml class
>   org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML
>   application context [springUrl=file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml, err=Error
>   creating bean with name 'ignite.cfg' defined in URL
>   [file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml]: Error setting property values; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'expiryPolicyFactory' of bean class
>   [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration]: Bean property
>   'expiryPolicyFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?]  at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1029)
>     at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:351)  at
>   org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
>   Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to
>   instantiate Spring XML application context
>   [springUrl=file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml, err=Error creating bean with
>   name 'ignite.cfg' defined in URL [file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml]: Error
>   setting property values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'expiryPolicyFactory' of bean class
>   [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration]: Bean property
>   'expiryPolicyFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?]  at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:392)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:751)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:952)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
>     at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)  ... 1 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'ignite.cfg' defined in URL
>   [file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml]: Error setting property values; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'expiryPolicyFactory' of bean class
>   [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration]: Bean property
>   'expiryPolicyFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:381)
>     ... 9 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'expiryPolicyFactory' of bean class
>   [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration]: Bean property
>   'expiryPolicyFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?   at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:239)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:435)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>     ... 20 more Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML
>   application context [springUrl=file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml, err=Error
>   creating bean with name 'ignite.cfg' defined in URL
>   [file:/path/to/etc/cache.xml]: Error setting property values; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'expiryPolicyFactory' of bean class
>   [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration]: Bean property
>   'expiryPolicyFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?]

I checked the source code for Ignite, and just like the exception states, `expiryPolicyFactory` is not a property on `org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration`.

The Ignite document that I'm using for the config (for setting the expiration policy) is here: 
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies
which states:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    ...

    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
        <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                    <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(I'm using Ignite 2.7.6.)

How am I supposed to define the expiration policy for Ignite?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the issue is that I was putting the config in the wrong location. I got this to config work:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="default"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="eagerTtl" value="true"/>
                <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                  <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                      <constructor-arg>
                          <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                              <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                              <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                          </bean>
                      </constructor-arg>
                  </bean>
              </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```